# Trace of the exponential matrix and its relation to the determinent of the argument

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

$\DeclareMathOperator{\trace}{trace}$
I am going through Rossmann's *'Lie Groups: An Introduction Through Linear Groups'*, and near the end of section 1.2 there is an example I don't quite understand (Example 9 in my edition). It is about solutions, $X$, to an equation of the form $$ \exp X = a$$. We assume $X$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix with trace zero. This allows us to obtain

$$ \exp X = (\cos \sqrt{\det{X}})1 + \frac{\sin \sqrt{\det{X}}}{\sqrt{\det{X}}}X.$$

So far so good. Now the book says that the above equation $$ \exp X = a$$ only has solutions when $\frac{1}{2} \trace a > -1$ or $a = -1$, and that in such a case for $-1 < \frac{1}{2} \trace a < 1$ the solution is given by

$$ X = \frac{\xi}{\sin \xi}(a-\frac{1}{2} \trace a 1),$$

where $\xi > 0$ satisfies $\cos \xi = \frac{1}{2} \trace a$. This is not clear to me. There seems to be some relationship here between $\trace a$ and $\det X$ which is not obvious to me. Could someone explain?

Edit: In light of one of the comment below, I'm expanding the post to include the follwing. @user1551 suggests that $\xi = \sqrt{\det{x}}$. Assuming $X$ to be in JNF form, we must have that the diagonal entries are such that

$$ \lambda_1 + \lambda_2 = 0 \rightarrow \lambda_2 = -\lambda_1$$

This would imply that

$$ \trace {a} = e^{\lambda_1} + e^{-\lambda_1}$$

and since $\det X = -\lambda_1^2$, we have

$$\trace{a} = 2 \cos\left({i \sqrt{\det{X}}}\right)$$.

But the equality does not hold without the $i$ in the argument. This is where I am confused.

Comment: $\xi$ is just $\sqrt{\det X}$.

Comment: It could be defined that way, though that would not guarantee $\xi > 0$. But if we take that then does this mean $\frac{1}{2} \trace{a} = \cos \sqrt{\det{X}}$?

Comment: No. $X$ is equal to $\frac{\xi}{\sin\xi}(\cdots)$ only for **some** $\xi$ that satisfies $\cos\xi=\frac12\operatorname{trace}(A)$, but not every solution $\xi$ to the equation $\cos\xi=\frac12\operatorname{trace}(A)$ produces a valid solution $X$ to the equation $\exp X=a$. Also, I think the author has implicitly assumed that $\det X\ge0$ (so that it is neither negative or non-real).

Comment: I'm a bit confused now. You are saying $\xi$ is just $\sqrt{\det{X}}$ (so it may be imaginary). But the book states $\xi > 0$. Also, I cannot reconcile the implication that $\frac{1}{2} \trace{a} = \cos \sqrt{\det{X}}$.

Comment: See edit to the OP.

Comment: I don't understand how you obtain $\operatorname{tr} a=2\cos(i\sqrt{\det X})$. Consider $\exp\pmatrix{0&-\pi\\ \pi&0}=-I$ for instance.